# PfSense - Ha proxy Wan Ip timeout when outside network requests

Tags: haproxy, pfsense

Currently I'm setting up a home lab and I've the following architecture

[Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKwnO.png)

I've setup my **ISP** provider to redirect any **80** requests to my pfsense firewall.

Created a rule allowing any requests from **external KONG SERVER** to port **80**
[Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y7DK.png)

Created an **HAPROXY** Front end listening to **PFSENSE** Wan address
[Frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYaMX.png)

And use a backend to my internal docker container
[Backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpzbV.png)

If I try to access my public ip address(which one I can get using [watsismyip](https://www.whatismyip.com/)) the api responds successfully.

But when I try to access it throught kong gateway, I receive a timeout.

> This tests was made by simpling make a curl request to my public ip address from kong server

Do you have any ideas why this is happening?

Is it something related to **NAT** outbound?

> As I'm a new user here I cant attach images to this post, so I've provided some hiperlinks to it